# SQL filter duplicates based on a set of values

Tags: sql

I have a table that lists all customer phone numbers, customers can have many phone numbers, EG , mobiles, Landline etc.

I only need 1 phone number per person for my purposes

In the Data i have a PersonID, that is duplicated for each phone record.

Result:
What i want is to have a query to show me unique PersonID's with thier Mobile Number, then if there is no mobile number, Show me Landline, then if no Landline show me Email.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure?

Comment: Do you want to actually remove records (as in your question title) or just filter them for output (as in your question)?

Comment: @Phil Filter them out i think, im writing a query to pull from a SQL Database, then i will produce a call list (one number per customer) in excel for the staff.

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa You want the headers?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff

`code`
PersonID | Contact Number Type | Contact Number
1 | Mobile | 123456789
1 | LandLine | 123456789
2| Mobile |213456478
2| Email | jndk@gmail.com
3| Email | jjksd@gmail.com
4| Landline | 347474734

So in this example, i would want to get: 

Person ID 1 and the Mobile
Person ID 2 and Mobile
Person ID 3 and email 
Person ID 4 and Landline
`code`

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select personid,
       coalesce( max(case when type = 'mobile' then phone end),
                 max(case when type = 'landline' then phone end),
                 max(email)
               )
from t
group by personid
```